# Moving text blocks using jQuery each

Tags: jquery

First off i'm using wordpress and contact form 7 plugin.

When I submit my form and the required fields are left empty it produces an error message.

This message appears below the field.
`<span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">The field is required.</span>`

What i'm trying to do is move this error above the relevent field.

**This is the form with the errors displayed**

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form wpcf7-acceptance-as-validation invalid" novalidate="novalidate">

    <h4>FIRST NAME: *</h4>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap firstname">
        <input name="firstname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="e.g. John" type="text">
        <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">The field is required.</span>
    </span>

    <h4>LAST NAME: *</h4>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap lastname">
        <input name="lastname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="e.g. Smith" type="text">
        <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">The field is required.</span>
    </span>

    <h4>EMAIL ADDRESS: *</h4>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap emailaddress">
        <input name="emailaddress" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="Email Address" type="email">
        <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">The field is required.</span>
    </span>

</form>
```

**This is the required output:**

```
    <form action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form wpcf7-acceptance-as-validation invalid" novalidate="novalidate">

        <h4>FIRST NAME: *</h4>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap firstname">
            <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">The field is required.</span>
            <input name="firstname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="e.g. John" type="text">
        </span>

        <h4>LAST NAME: *</h4>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap lastname">
            <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">The field is required.</span>
            <input name="lastname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="e.g. Smith" type="text">
        </span>

        <h4>EMAIL ADDRESS: *</h4>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap emailaddress">
            <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">The field is required.</span>
            <input name="emailaddress" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="Email Address" type="email">
        </span>

    </form>
```

I'm using jQuery which is where I come unstuck.
I'm having trouble with `.each()` not working as I expect it too.

**This is my jQuery:**

```js
$(".wpcf7").on('invalid.wpcf7',function(e){
    var error_msg = $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip');
    error_msg.each( function() {
        $(this).parent('.wpcf7-form-control-wrap').prepend(error_msg);
    });
});
```

`'invalid.wpcf7'` is one of the callback functions of the form.

But what this is doing is appending all the error messages to the first `'.wpcf7-form-control-wrap'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to prepend the current error message, not all error messages:

```
$(this).parent('.wpcf7-form-control-wrap').prepend(this);
```

Your code was doing the following:

```
...prepend(error_msg);
```

However, `error_msg` is the collection that you are iterating over. In other words, it's *all* of your error messages, not just the current one in your loop.

Comment: Any reason why this would add it to each of the parent items and my version above was adding this only to the first parent?

Comment: @Anthony I have to wait 3 mins mate

Comment: @Aaron - updated the answer. Not sure why it was adding everything to the first parent. I would have expected it to add everything to the last parent, but obviously there's an additional layer I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Oh! it's based on how long the question has existed, not how long the answer has existed. That makes a bit more sense. Probably cuts down a bit on people posting answers to their own questions with "oops, I had to change this thing" and then marking their own answer as accepted. Anyways, didn't mean to be too much of a jerk, just a little bit of one to make sure the answer was accepted.